# Can an internal SCSI cable be terminated in the middle?

Tags: scsi

I have an internal 68-pin SCSI cable with space for 5 devices. The cable is damaged between the 3rd and 4th space and prevents the drive in the 1st space (the only drive) from functioning. In most cases, I would just replace the cable. But the connector to the motherboard is proprietary and near impossible to find a replacement for.

Would it be feasible to place a terminator in the 2nd space and have it function? The cable has a terminator at the end, but it's soldered in place. Alternatively, could I just snip off the cable right before the break and put the terminator there?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the rest of the connectors you can terminate the cable in the middle - however, I'd strongly suggest cutting off the damaged half of the cable.